# I face a problem in the array I get the data from firebase (firestore) and I want to show array of data how can i do?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
//data from Firebase 
[
  {
    "Role": "Student",
    "Section": "A",
    "StudentEmail": "amir@gmail.com",
    "StudentFather": "Atif Mian",
    "StudentID": "Bs-2000",
    "StudentName": "Amir Liaqat",
    "Subject": ["Web", "app"],
    "uid": "atwYEXNseKYyXfnTpldcTyL2Hj83"
  }
]
```

I want to get only `"Subject": ["Web", "app"]` in the form of list

I used the code below but I think it was wrong

```
{subject
  ? subject.map((a, i) => {
      return <Text key={i}>{a}</Text>
    })
  : <></>
}
```

I received result `"WebApp"` but I need in the form of list.

I receive the data from there

```
const [subject, setSubject] = useState();

firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .where('uid', '==', StudentUID)
  .onSnapshot({
    error: e => console.error(e),
    next: querySnapshot => {
      var data = [];
      var sub = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        data.push(doc.data());
        sub.push(doc.data().Subject);
      });
      setStudents(data);
      setSubject(sub)
      console.log(sub)
    },
  });
```

Comment: How are you getting the value in subject? Please add the missing code which includes your Firebase query.

Comment: firestore().collection('users').doc(StudentUID).update({
      Subject: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(subject),})

I used this code to enter the value in firebase
using TextInput I enter the data from user

Comment: Please edit your question when adding information. Specifically, please add the code where you are receiving data, not updating data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `subject` state is the array of `Subject` properties, also an array, from the data containing objects like the following:

```
[
  {
    "Role": "Student",
    "Section": "A",
    "StudentEmail": "amir@gmail.com",
    "StudentFather": "Atif Mian",
    "StudentID": "Bs-2000",
    "StudentName": "Amir Liaqat",
    "Subject": ["Web", "app"],
    "uid": "atwYEXNseKYyXfnTpldcTyL2Hj83"
  },
]
```

Then this means the `subject` state is an array of arrays, i.e. `[["Web", "app"], ...]`. `["Web", "app"]` is valid JSX and will pretty much be rendered directly as is, one string value then the other, with no separator characters, e.g. `"Webapp"`.

The simplest solution would be to join this array and convert it to a string when mapping, specifying the separator character you'd like, i.e. `"Web, app"`.

Example:

```
const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]); // <-- valid initial state

...

firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .where('uid', '==', StudentUID)
  .onSnapshot({
    error: e => console.error(e),
    next: querySnapshot => {
      var data = [];
      var sub = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        data.push(doc.data());
        sub.push(doc.data().Subject);
      });
      setStudents(data);
      setSubjects(sub);
    },
  });

...

{subjects.map((subject, i) => (
  <Text key={i}>{subject.join(", ")}</Text> // `["Web", "app"]` => "Web, app"
)}
```

There is no need really to duplicate this subject state, you can easily map it from the `students` state.

```
{students.map(({ StudentID, Subject }) => (
  <Text key={StudentID}>{Subject.join(", ")}</Text> // "Web, app"
)}
```